# Convert an array of string dates to timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date, datetime

I have a form with an input box named "date[]" and a button that allows you to create more rows to add more dates, all with the name "date[]". The date picker format in my text input box is m-d-Y (03-15-2015). When I submit the form I need to convert the array of dates to mysql Date format Y-m-d (2015-03-15). Iv successfully captured the array of dates in an array in my php script and I'm trying to do a foreach loop and convert each date[]value into a timestamp using 'strtotime', that i will then convert to the correct  Y-m-d format. The problem is strtotime expects a string not an array.

My question is how can I go about iterating through each date[] value and converting it into a timestamp? There is not a fixed amount of dates, it can change with each user.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You said 'strtotime expects a string not an array'. Also you mentioned that you successfully captured the array of dates, and you are looping over it to extract each date from the array. So now, what you have is each date, which is of type String. So what's the issue?. Since you haven't shared any code, I can't tell you specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [array_map()](http://php.net/array_map) or [array_walk()](http://php.net/array_walk)

Here's an array_walk example that let's you specify the formats at call-time.

```
$dates = ['03-15-2015', '05-29-2015'];
array_walk($dates, function(&$date, $i, $formats)
{
    $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($formats['from'], $date);
    $date = $datetime->format($formats['to']);
}, ['from' => 'm-d-Y', 'to' => 'Y-m-d']);
```

Comment: Thats pretty nifty right there. Thank you for your response. Its printing in the correct format now.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach :

```
$dates = $_POST['date']; // in case you are using POST request
foreach($dates as $date){
  $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $date); 
  $cDates[] = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
 }
```

Now all the converted dates exist inside $cDates array.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was capturing the array like "$dates[] = $_post...". However when i print the array I get the famous 1970-01-01, instead of the actual date... and when I do the iteration with just strtotime and print, the array is empty. So this might be where its going wrong...

Comment: it's my fault .. i thought the $_POST date is in d-m-y format but it's in m-d-y instead ..  it's appear that strtotime don't accept that format